# I programming puzzles, il code golf

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

## Background

The Italian definite article (corresponding to English *the*) has seven different forms: *l'*, *il*, *lo*, *gli*, *i*, *la*, *le*. Which one to use depends on three variables:

- Gender: masculine / feminine.
- Number: singular / plural.
- Initial letter of the subsequent word: vowel / consonant type A / consonant type B.

  - Vowel is any of these: *aeiou*.
  - Consonant type B is any of these cases: *s-* followed by another consonant, *z-*, *gn-*, *pn-*, *ps-*, *x-*, *i-* followed by vowel (this *i* acts as a semivowel).
  - Consonant type A is a consonant that is not type B.

The table shows the article form to be used in each of the twelve combinations of the three above variables. Note that the *l'* form is attached to the following word with a single quote and without a space.

[image]

## The challenge

Input **a word** and one or two strings, numbers or Booleans indicating **gender** and **number**. (The initial letters will have to be obtained from the input word).

The input word will be a sequence of lowercase ASCII letters. Accented vowels will be replaced by their non-accented versions (for example, *realtà* will be input as *realta*).

The gender and number inputs can be separate numbers, Booleans or strings, or a combined number of string (for example, 1 for masculine singular, 2 for feminine singular, etc).

Any reasonable format and separator can be used, as long as it is specified in the answer.

Output the **word preceded by the appropriate form of the article**, with space or single quote as needed. The output should also be lowercase. Trailing or leading blank space is allowed.

Code golf, shortest wins.

## Test cases

In the following I use the input letters `m`, `f` to specify gender, and `s`, `p` for number (this is just one possible input format).

```
Input               Output              Comment

macchina f s        la macchina         Initial letter is cons. A
zio m s             lo zio              Initial letter is cons. B
libri m p           i libri             Initial letter is cons. A
ieri m s            lo ieri             Initial letter is cons. B
aquile f p          le aquile           Initial letter is vowel
spagnoli m p        gli spagnoli        Initial letter is cons. B
golf m s            il golf             Initial letter is cons. A
ombra f s           l'ombra             Initial letter is vowel
impossibili m p     gli impossibili     Initial letter is vowel
```

Comment: You may want to also make a challenge on the coniugation of regular verbs.

Comment: @user6245072 Well, there's already [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68591/36398)... the difference would probably be too small

Comment: A minor technical niggle: /j/ is normally called a _semivowel_ in English, not a _semiconsonant_. I wonder what the solutions would be if they were to factor in edge cases like ⟨ch⟩ representing [ʃ] rather than [k] (_lo chef_, _lo chardonnay_), the variation with French names (_l’Havet_ but _lo Hugo_), fossilised forms (_gli dei_, _per lo meno_), women referred to by their last name (_l’Antonia_ but _la Antonini_), etc. That would be quite the formidable thing to golf-code.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh, I thought it was called semiconsonant also in English (as in Spanish) when it appears in the beginning of a syllable. I've corrected it. I had no idea about _gli dei_ or _per lo meno_. Thanks for the information!

Comment: As Italian I ask you to take off `ieri` test case because is an adverb and not a noun! (BTW it was formally correct) Please!

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello I know it's an adverb, but it's also [used as a noun](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ieri-oggi-e-domani.2172624/), isn't it?, as it is [in English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/yesterday) and [in Spanish](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4c9npT2). Anyway, if you think it's too streched, can you suggest a noun that starts with semiconsonant "i-"?

Comment: In 21 years of life in Italy I never seen _Ieri_ used as a noun, but i know it's formally correct! In only sounds awful in my head... And then, It's a Code-Golf! If we don't need a clean code, we also don't need a clean language, if it works!

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello So can't you say something like "Non pensare allo ieri, pensa allo domani" (non-native here)

Comment: We usally say: "Non pensare __a__ ieri, Pensa __a__ Domani"

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello Anyway, isn't _ieri_ and _domani_ nouns there? :-)

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello Thanks for the idea anyway. I think I'll leave "ieri" because quite a few answers are using it as a test case

Comment: Good Check! But in special cases like this one we don't use the Articles! We use the preposition. Before I've mispelled... `I never seen Ieri used as a noun` had to be __I never seen Ieri used as a noun with a defined Article__ (My awful English didn't help me explaining italian grammar :-P ) I cant think about a phrase with _lo Ieri_ in the Italian common language :-D

Comment: @GiacomoGarabello Got it. Thanks for the tip! E spero che possiamo parlare (scrivere) in italiano alcuna volta se visiterai lo chat :-)

Comment: Of course you can keep it, It's Correct! My only word about that it's  uncommon and we don't use it that much (and it's sound is awful)! P.S.:  Se vuoi Imparare l'italiano spero di poterti essere di aiuto!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Retina, <s>138</s> <s>133</s> <s>129</s> 113 bytes

```
^.(s[^aeiou]|z|gn|pn|ps|x|i[aeiou])
B$&
^.[aeiou]
V$&
^\d.
A$&
V[02]
l'
A0
il 
B0
lo 
A1
i 
.1
gli 
.2
la 
.3
le
```

[Test suite.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApeLihzW15hZWlvdV18enxnbnxwbnxwc3x4fGlbYWVpb3VdKQpCJCYKXi5bYWVpb3VdClYkJgpeXGQuCkEkJgpWWzAyXQpsJwpBMAppbCAKQjAKbG8gCkExCmkgCi4xCmdsaSAKLjIKbGEgCi4zCmxlIA&input=Mm1hY2NoaW5hCjB6aW8KMWxpYnJpCjBpZXJpCjNhcXVpbGUKMXNwYWdub2xpCjBnb2xmCjJvbWJyYQoxaW1wb3NzaWJpbGk)
(prepended `` %(G`\n `` to run all test-cases at once)

Input format: `macchina f s` becomes `2macchina` instead.

```
0: Masculine Singular
1: Masculine Plural
2: Feminine Singular
3: Feminine Plural
```

Conversion table thanks to [Kevin Lau](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85493/48934).

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3.5, <s>238</s> <s>235</s> <s>192</s> <s>181</s> 178 bytes:

(*-13 bytes thanks to tips from Leaky Nun!*)

```
import re;R=re.match;lambda a,b:(R('s[^aeiou]|(z|gn|pn|ps|x|i)[aeiou]',a)and['lo ','gli ','la '][b]or R('[aeiou]',a)and["l'",'gli '][b%2]or['il ','i ','la '][b]if b<3else'le ')+a
```

An anonymous lambda function that takes arguments in the form of `(<String>, <Integer Gender-Plurality mapping>)`, where the mapping is as follows:

```
0 -> Masculine Singular
1 -> Masculine Plural
2 -> Feminine Singular
3 -> Feminine Plural
```

To call it, simply give the function any valid name, and then call it like a normal function wrapped inside a print statement. Therefore, if the question were to be named `U`, simply call it like `print(U(<String>, <Integer Gender-Plurality mapping>))`.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](https://ideone.com/EjFmf2)

Comment: `zzz and yyy or xxx` is two bytes shorter than `[xxx,yyy][bool(zzz)]`

Comment: @LeakyNun I can do that? Wow, I did not even know. Thanks! :)

Comment: It works as long as `yyy` is truthy.

Comment: @LeakyNun Yeah, of course.

Comment: `["l'",'gli '][b%2]` is 3 bytes shorter than `["l'",'gli ',"l'"][b]`

Comment: @LeakyNun Wow, genius! I did not think of that! Thanks again! :)

Comment: I believe you can use `and` `or` to replace `if` `else`.

Comment: @LeakyNun Yeah, that is just what I was about to do.

Comment: @LeakyNun Actually, that is 2 bytes longer since I have use more parenthesis in that case.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, <s>227</s> <s>208</s> 195 bytes

*-13 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun*

```
String f(String a,int o){boolean v=a.matches("^([aeou]|i[^aeiou]).*"),b=a.matches("^([ixz]|gn|pn|ps|s[^aeiou]).*");return(o>1?o>2?"le ":v?"l'":"la ":o>0?v||b?"gli ":"i ":v?"l'":b?"lo ":"il ")+a;}
```

Takes your string and an int based on the following mapping:

```
0: Masculine Singular
1: Masculine Plural
2: Feminine Singular
3: Feminine Plural
```

Returns a string with the result.

Ungolfed with test cases and with no ternary operators (for real now):

```
class Test {

    public static String f(String a, int o) {
        boolean v = a.matches("^([aeou]|i[^aeiou]).*");
        boolean b = a.matches("^([ixz]|gn|pn|ps|s[^aeiou]).*");
        String r;
        if(o > 1)
            if(o > 2)
                r = "le ";
            else
                if(v)
                    r = "l'";
                else
                    r = "la ";
        else
            if(o > 0)
                if(v || b)
                    r = "gli ";
                else
                    r = "i ";
            else
                if(v)
                    r = "l'";
                else if(b)
                    r = "lo ";
                else
                    r = "il ";
        return r + a;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(f("macchina", 2));
        System.out.println(f("zio", 0));
        System.out.println(f("libri", 1));
        System.out.println(f("ieri", 0));
        System.out.println(f("aquile", 3));
        System.out.println(f("spagnoli", 1));
        System.out.println(f("golf", 0));
        System.out.println(f("ombra", 2));
        System.out.println(f("impossibili", 1));
    }
}
```

Uses a little bit of regex magic and acts depending on the two booleans specified. To my surprise, no imports are needed, which helps out with the code size!

Comment: Mine is...longer than JAVA?! I must golf mine down a bit more asap! Good job though! +1

Comment: If I had to take my arguments from the command line or stdin, believe me, it would have been a lot longer :P

Comment: Yes, Booleans accepted too. I've edited that in

Comment: I think you can use `0/1` instead of `false/true` which should save you some bytes.

Comment: Not using `String e = "[^aeiou]).*";` actually saves you 5 bytes.

Comment: Your ungolfed code still has 3 ternary operators.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>147</s> 146 bytes

[Try it online?](https://repl.it/Cc7O/1)

It might be possible to use a better method to determine which article to use, but I'm not aware of any.

As per the spec, the identifier is a number, as follows:

```
0: Masculine Singular
1: Masculine Plural
2: Feminine Singular
3: Feminine Plural
```

---

```
->w,i{(%w"lo gli la le l' gli l' le il i la le"[(0..2).find{|r|[/^(i[aeiou]|s[^aeiou]|z|x|[gp]n|ps)/,/^[aeiou]/,//][r]=~w}*4+i]+' '+w).sub"' ",?'}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Batch, <s>446</s> <s>390</s> <s>385</s> 380 bytes

```
@echo off
set w=%2
call:l %1 l' gli_ l' le_ il_ i_ la_ le_ lo_ gli_ le_ le_
exit/b
:l
for /l %%a in (0,1,%1)do shift
set o=%5
for %%a in (gn pn ps)do if %%a==%w:~,2% set o=%9
for %%a in (s z x)do if %%a==%w:~,1% set o=%9
for %%a in (a e i o u)do if %%a==%w:~,1% set o=%1
for %%a in (a e i o u)do if i%%a==%w:~,2% (set o=%9)else if s%%a==%w:~,2% set o=%1
echo %o:_= %%w%
```

New version uses the same `0-3` encoding for the gender and number as several other answers. Works by creating a 1-dimensional array `%2` .. `%13` of forms, then shifting out the first `1+%1` elements so that the forms of interest become `%1`, `%5` and `%9` (which is fortunate as Batch won't go above `%9` without shifting). It then laboriously checks the lists of prefixes to find out which form needs to be used. `_` is used as a placeholder to represent a space until the word is output.

Comment: Might as well have them encoded into a single digit (or letter if needed, since the spec allows it) to save bytes. Everything is for the sake of the bytes!

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny Switching to digit encoding allowed me to save a whopping 56 bytes by rewriting the gender and number handling!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 235 bytes

I was interested to see how short I could get this in Python without regexes. It turns out that this is not the best option...

```
lambda s,c,v='aeiou':[["l'",'il','lo'],['gli','i','gli'],["l'",'la','la'],['le']*3][c][[[1,2][s[0]=='s'and s[1]not in v or s[0]in'zx'or s[:2]in['gn','pn','ps']or s[0]=='i'and s[1]in v],0][s[0]in v and not(s[0]=='i'and s[1]in v)]]+' '+s
```

An anonymous function that takes input via argument of the word `s` and the gender-number code `c` as an integer, using the following mapping:

```
0 - Masculine Singular
1 - Masculine Plural
2 - Feminine Singular
3 - Feminine Plural
```

and returns the word with the correct article.

**How it works**

A list containing the possibilities for each `c` as separate lists is created. The list is then indexed into using the value of `c`, yielding a 3-element list with the relevant options. A list index is now chosen by indexing into another nested list with the results of Boolean expressions. If the first character of `s` is a vowel and is not `i` followed by a vowel, the option for `vowel` is yielded via the returning of the index `0`. Else, a Boolean expression returning `True` for `cons. B` and `False` for `cons. A` is evaluated, yielding the indices `2` and `1` respectively. Finally, the index is used to yield the article, which is concatenated with a space and the original string before being returned.

[Try it on Ideone](https://ideone.com/67PBkv)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript 210 bytes

```
(s,p)=>{var c=i=>!("aeiou".indexOf(s[i])+1),r=["z","gn","pn","ps","x"].some(t=>!s.indexOf(t))||(c(1)?s[0]=="s":s[0]=="i")?2:c(0)?1:0;return (p&1?(p&2?"le ":r&1?"i ":"gli "):!r?"l'":p&2?"la ":r&1?"il ":"lo ")+s}
```

An anonymous function taking two parameters s and p where

```
s  is the input string
p  is plurality (bit 0, set=plural) and gender (bit 1, set=f) combined as
    0 = masculine singular
    1 = masculine plural
    2 = feminine singular
    3 = feminine plural
```

After assigning the function to a variable and some unpacking), it can be tested as

```
var f=(s,p)=>{
    var c = i=>!("aeiou".indexOf(s[i])+1),
        r = ["z","gn","pn","ps","x"].some(t=>!s.indexOf(t))
             || ( c(1)? s[0]=="s":s[0]=="i" )
             ?   2 : c(0) ? 1 : 0;

     return (p&1?(p&2?"le ":r&1?"i ":"gli "):!r?"l'":p&2?"la ":r&1?"il ":"lo ")+s;
}

console.log("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",
 f("macchina",2),
 f("zio",0),
 f("libri",1),
 f("ieri", 0),
 f("aquile",3),
 f("spagnoli",1),
 f("golf",0),
 f("ombra",2),
 f("impossibili",1))
```

where

- `c` is a function to test `s` for a consonant at position `i`.
- `r` evaluates to 0 for starting with a vowel, 1 for starting with a type A consonant and 2 for starting with a type B consonant (tested in reverse order).
- Bit bashing in the return statement puts it together.